# Which of the following is correct: She will visit her friend soon or She will be visiting her friend soon

Tags: future-tense

Which of the following is correct: 
She will visit her friend soon
Or 
She will be visiting her friend soon

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. In order for us to answer your question, you must [edit] it to explain why you think one or the other is or is not correct, citing what you know about the use of the continuous aspect. Otherwise, this becomes a proofreading exercise that is not helpful to future visitors who have the same question. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct future tense.

First one is simple future tense and the latter one is Future continuous/Progressive tense.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.

The first version says the visit will happen. This is the common way it will be said.

The second version says there will be a point in time when she is actively visiting. That is a rather subtle distinction, and it is generally a useless distinction. It will be rather uncommon for anyone to say it this way.